# How to store gameobjects position to play games service unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, google-play-games

I have made a simple project where In the scene when I tap/click on the screen I instantiate gameObjects on a plane and also store all there transform to a list.

[image]
I want to use the play games services to save the position/transforms of the gameObjects on the cloud so as to when I delete the app and install it again the gameObjects are instantiated on the same location.

I use this [autosave](https://pastebin.com/PG6JJue0) `code` for play service login and saving the int and string value.
How do I make the positions of the gameObjects(e.g. in project - cubes) to be saved on play games so when I install it again with same account I get the gameObject position so they can be instantiated again automatically